# Can't get attribute 'CronTrigger'

Tags: django, apscheduler

```
Unable to restore job "b'30'" -- removing it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/py3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/redis.py", line 131, in _reconstitute_jobs
    jobs.append(self._reconstitute_job(job_state))
  File "/opt/py3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/redis.py", line 119, in _reconstitute_job
    job_state = pickle.loads(job_state)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'CronTrigger' on <module 'apscheduler.triggers.cron' from '/opt/py3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/triggers/cron/__init__.py'>
```

Random errors encountered after Django restart,I don't know why

```
def add_daily_task(task_id):
    crontab = CrontabTask.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    scheduler.add_job(func=crontab_task,
                      args=[task_id],
                      trigger=CronTrigger.from_crontab('%s %s %s %s %s' % (crontab.crontab_minute,
                                                           crontab.crontab_hour,
                                                           crontab.crontab_day,
                                                           crontab.crontab_month,
                                                           crontab.crontab_week)),
                      id=str(task_id),
                      jobstore='eazyops',
                      replace_existing=True)
```

this my add_job code